# Example of global holomorphic form which is not closed.

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. Any global holomorphic $k$-form $\omega \in H^0(X, \Omega^k)$ is automatically harmonic with respect to any choice of hermitian structure on $X$. When $X$ is Kähler, by the Kähler identities, this implies that $\mathrm{d}{\omega} = 0$.

I am wondering if the same is true when $X$ is not Kähler. If not, what is an example of a nonclosed global holomorphic $k$-form.

Comment: As pointed out by Gunnar Þór Magnússon below, there is a non-closed holomorphic one-form on the Iwasawa manifold which is three-dimensional. This is the lowest dimensional example because one can show that on an $n$-dimensional compact complex manifold, holomorphic $(n-1)$-forms and holomorphic $n$-forms are closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens on the Iwasawa manifold.

Let $G$ be the Heisenberg group of complex upper-triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices
$$
G = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & y \\
0 & 1 & z \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and let $\Gamma \subset G$ be the discrete subgroup generated by matrices whose non-diagonal entries are Gaussian integers. The Iwasawa manifold is the quotient $X := G / \Gamma$. It is a compact complex manifold.

There are three linearly independent holomorphic forms on $X$: $\alpha = dx$, $\beta = dy$ and $\gamma = dz - x \, dy$. They're defined by looking at the entries of $M^{-1} \, dM$ for $M(x,y,z) \in G$.

We see that $d \gamma = - \alpha \wedge \beta \not= 0$, so $\gamma$ is a non-closed holomorphic form. In particular, this proves $X$ is not Kahler.

The facts here are pretty much verbatim from Michel Schweitzer's manuscript [Autour de la cohomologie de Bott-Chern](http://Autour%20de%20la%20cohomologie%20de%20Bott-Chern).